# Vue toggle won't revert back, only toggles one way and once

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I feel like this should be working and is rather simple, but I can't for the life of me figure this out. I'm making a button currently that starts with "Pause" as the text, then when pressed the button text changes to Resume

This works perfectly, but it never toggles back to resume?? I need this to be a one to one toggle, simply clicking changes it from one to the other.

What am I doing wrong here?

template

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" v-on:click="pauseTask" type="button" role="button" id="" aria-expanded="false" style=" color: #6c757d border:none; border-radius: .15;">
    {{ pauseButton.text }}
</button>
```

Vue

```
data() {
    return {
        pauseButton: {
            text:'Pause'
        },
        isOpen: true
    }
},
pauseTask: function() {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
      this.pauseButton.text = app.isOpen ? 'Pause' : 'Resume';
    },
```

Comment: `app.isOpen` should be `this.isOpen`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo due to your use of the undefined `app` variable.

I would suggest you use a computed property to decide what text to show so you're not maintaining two separate data properties.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({ isOpen: true }),
  computed: {
    pauseButtonText () {
      return this.isOpen ? 'Pause' : 'Resume'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    togglePause () {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="togglePause" type="button">
      {{ pauseButtonText }}
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah that was it! Thanks a lot

Comment: @TomN. pay attention to the redesign as well.  Seperating out the toggle ( which I'd actually make a function for rather than embedding in the click ) from the text makes your code more modular

Comment: @KeithNicholas If the toggle was anything more than just flipping a single Boolean, I would agree that moving it to a method is better but for this simple case, I don't see any problem with using a template expression

Comment: fair enough, I don't do it based on whether it's trivially simple, more a design thing, so events get tied to actions, implementation is inside the actions, any other UI element can trigger that action if needed and the action can easily be extended, just more modular... if it's a habit then you can always make good assumptions about where functionality is .  But yeah for a SO answer / trivial examples ... not a big deal

Comment: @KeithNicholas excellent points. I've updated my answer to use a method